# PHPMyAdmin not letting me import .sql file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to import the following .sql file, containing:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `login`.`users` (
 `user_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT  'auto incrementing user_id of each user, unique index',
 `user_name` VARCHAR( 64 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s name, unique',
 `user_password_hash` VARCHAR( 255 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
 `user_email` VARCHAR( 64 ) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT  'user''s email, unique',
PRIMARY KEY (  `user_id` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `user_name` (  `user_name` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `user_email` (  `user_email` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT =  'user data';
```

but it gives me the error

```
#1142 - CREATE command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'users'
```

What's the problem here and how can I solve this?

Comment: Your user probably lacks the necessary permissions.

Comment: @tftd So there's no way of solving this, rather than contacting my host?

Comment: You could try exporting the SQL without creating tables ie a simple data export. Would need to take precautions against duplicate entries though if you then run the SQL on an older version of the DB that had previous data int it

Comment: Well in your error user name not mention. check your user name, password and permission.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful.

Go to `phpMyAdmin -> users`, select the user you want to change and give all the privileges.

Comment: That option isn't there. Does this mean that I'm not allowed to change the privileges?

Comment: Ok, then try to locate in your host control panel your mySQL users. Which is your hosting provider?

Comment: hostfree.nl is my hosting provider. -- I'm testing the files there, after they're bug free, I'm uploading them to a non-free domain.

Answer (score 0):

As some of the others have said, you appear to lack privileges to create a table in the `login` database. Given the error message which references the user ''@'localhost', this is almost certainly because you're not logged in as your actual user, but instead are the anonymous user. Check your username and password against what the host provided, try logging in via the command-line client if available, and be aware of your host and connection type.

You're connecting via sockets, which means your user account has to have the host 'localhost'. If your user only has the host '%' then you'll have to either ask your host for the 'localhost' privilege or configure phpMyAdmin to connect via TCP/IP due to how MySQL handles incoming connections and the wildcard privilege.